# Using pivot_table or pd.groupby for certain seasons

Tags: python, pandas

I have data set like below:

```
      Year Month  Dryden  3rdAve  Clark  Landfill
0      2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
1      2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
2      2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
3      2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
4      2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
5      2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
6      2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
7      2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
8      2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
9      2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
10     2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
11     2015     1    0.00    0.00    0.0       NaN
```

where I want to run the code below to calculate the mean of each season for Dryden values:

```
df.Dryden.groupby([df.Year,pd.cut(df.Month,[0,3,6,9,12],labels=['Winter','Spring','Summer','Autumn'],right =False)]).mean()
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

df.dtype gives me:

```
Year          int64
Month        object
Dryden      float64
3rdAve      float64
Clark       float64
Landfill    float64
dtype: object
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me.

Comment: Can't replicate the issue but looking at your dtypes, you should convert `Month` to an `int`. That'll resolve your issue

Comment: I am reading the data like this  raw_data=pd.read_csv('District_data_2015_2017.csv',dtype = {'Month':'int'})     but again an error pops : invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#VALUE!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your Month column to an integer like this:

```
df.Month = df.Month.astype(int)
```

Then run your code:

```
In [61]: df.Dryden.groupby([df.Year,pd.cut(df.Month,[0,3,6,9,12],labels=['Winter','Spring','Summer','Autumn'],right =False)]).mean()
Out[61]: 
Year  Month 
2015  Winter    0.0
Name: Dryden, dtype: float64
```

If you're getting a value error, perhaps this works instead:

```
df.Month = pd.to_numeric(df.Month, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#VALUE!' The problem is its not converting it due to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
df['Month'] = df['Month'].astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['Month'] = df['Month'].astype(float).astype(int)
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#VALUE!'
The problem is its not converting it due to this error.